# why i can't downgrade pandas1.5.3?

Tags: python, pandas, downgrade

I had already upgrade my pandas to version=2.2.0.
I need to downgrade my pandas for `.iteritems`.
When I downgrade with following code:

```
pip install pandas==1.5.3
```

It's showing me below error:

```
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

reference - [ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey8Oj.png)

Can anyone help me to avoid this error.

Comment: Please do not post errors as images. [There are no pre-builds of 1.5.3 for py3.12](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.5.3/#files), so Python is trying to built it. Either install what the error tells you or use Python 3.11.

Comment: You need Microsoft Visual C++ > than 14.0. That what the error saying.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to downgrade your pandas.

You can add these lines on top of your code with `pandas 2.2.0`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.iteritems = pd.DataFrame.items
```